# How to upload JSON file to create Object in Javascript Runtime without changing server side script?

Tags: php, javascript, json, html, web-applications

How to upload JSON file to create Object in Javascript Runtime without request/respond with server side script ?

I have found the way to do it

JSON file >> (Upload via PHP to) >> Javascript >> Object in Runtime

But I don't want to use the php
How to do it by this way ?

JSON FILE >>>> (Upload directly to) >>>> Javascript >>>>Object in Runtime.

THANKS.

update:

I am trying to solve this problem by looking for new feature in HTML5 such as local storage, index eddb, websql, application cache.

Comment: via Javascript you might want to check out [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript runs on client side, and your json file is on server so you need to do it through server side script, you cannot access server side file from client side javascript.

If it is client side file you can read it using FileReader in javascript

```
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function() {
     console.log(this.result);            
   }
   reader.readAsText(file)
```

Comment: I mean that .JSON file is from user client side not the server.

Comment: Ohk then you can read it using FileReader in javascript\

       var reader = new FileReader();
       reader.onload = function() {
         console.log(this.result);            
       }
       reader.readAsText(file)